# MongoDB projection in .find() not renaming fields

Tags: mongodb

I've got a simple query written against a collection of readings, on which I am attempting to use the built-in projection optional parameter:

```
db.getCollection('readings').find(someQuery, { words: { $slice: ["$words", 10] }})
```

When I do this, the `words` array comes back with only 10 elements, as I expect. However, I'd like to rename the `words` array to `words_preview`. When I change this:

```
db.getCollection('readings').find(someQuery, { words_preview: { $slice: ["$words", 10] }})
```

the field does not appear on the reading at all. I'm familiar with the `$project` operator in aggregations, but this is my first time using the optional parameter after the query in `.find()`. Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is this not possible in this context?

Comment: projection in regular query doesn't allow shaping of result. It should be trivial on client side though.

Comment: Ah, too bad. It would be trivial, true. I'll just have to live with it